# Limiting the information displayed on the "Ready to Install" page in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

This does not make sense to me. I have adjusted my installer like this:

```
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    { We don't want to show these pages if we are upgrading. }
    if ((PageID = wpSelectDir) or 
      (PageID = wpSelectProgramGroup) or
      (PageID = wpSelectTasks) or
      (PageID = pageAutoBackup.ID)) then
        Result := bIsUpgrading
    else
        Result := False;

  DwinsHs_ShouldSkipPage(PageID, Result);
end;
```

`bIsUpgrading` is defined here:

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  // Are we performing an upgrade?
  bIsUpgrading := IsUpgrading();
end;
```

Now, here is my memo method:

```
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, 
                         NewLine, 
                         MemoUserInfoInfo, 
                         MemoDirInfo, 
                         MemoTypeInfo, 
                         MemoComponentsInfo, 
                         MemoGroupInfo, 
                         MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoDirInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoTasksInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  Result := Result + AutoBackupPage_MemoInfo(Space, NewLine);
  Result := Result + DwinsHs_MemoDownloadInfo(Space, NewLine);
end;
```

When I run this installer, as expected, the pages are not displayed. Yet the **Ready to Install** page still looks like this:

[image: Memo Page]

I did not expect to see that info displayed since we never showed those pages to the user.

I realise that I can adjust the logic like this:

```
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, 
                         NewLine, 
                         MemoUserInfoInfo, 
                         MemoDirInfo, 
                         MemoTypeInfo, 
                         MemoComponentsInfo, 
                         MemoGroupInfo, 
                         MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoDirInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
  if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then
    Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if(not bIsUpgrading) then
  begin
    if (MemoTasksInfo <> '') then
      Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    Result := Result + AutoBackupPage_MemoInfo(Space, NewLine);
  end;

  Result := Result + DwinsHs_MemoDownloadInfo(Space, NewLine);
end;
```

That improves things:

[image]

But why wasn't the various `Memo...` text strings empty if the pages were never displayed to the user?

And, how do we suppress the "Start Menu Folder"  info if we are upgrading?

Comment: I believe it's as designed. Skipping the pages do not disable their functionality. All the information on those pages is still considered when installing.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OK. I kind of feel if they are not displayed then they should noT show their actions.  Not to worry. If it is by design, it is by design.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have added a new check function `IsNewInstall`. The "task" items now have this check parameter. This means they only show in the memo info if they had passed the test. So I have been able to remove the `MemoTasksInfo ` from inside my special `if` check leaving just the backup settings there.

Comment: Yes, by `Check` you remove the task (including its functionality).